# Derivative of integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that

$$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)\; dy ds$$

and $\Phi, f$ are smoth functions with bounded derivatives. My question is why can we set the following identity:

$$ u_t(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Phi(y,s)f_t(x-y,t-s)\; dy ds+\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Phi(y,t)f(x-y,0)\; dy$$

I can recognize the FTC in the second integral and properties of convolution in the first one, but I can't understand the global identity. Any hel will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), where the notations from wikipedia here correspond to  "$a(x)\leftarrow 0$", "$b(x)\leftarrow t$" and "$f(x)\leftarrow\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)\,dyds$, 
it comes that:

\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \phi(y,t)f(x-y,t-t)\,dy - 0 +\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\phi(y,s)f_t(x-y,t-s)\,dyds
\end{equation}
which is the expected result.

Comment: I suppose because it's $f(x,b(x))$ so $s=t$ in the first integral. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @DiegoVargas right, corrected!